# Celery class based tasks group

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a task that create a few other parallel tasks using Celery's `group` method.

Initially these tasks were methods:

`@celery.task def my_task(): print('hi')`

And I can create that task in my other task using:

`group((my_task.s() for i in range(10))()`

Now, I want to change my method to a class:

`class MyTask(Celery.Task): def run(self, *args, **kwargs): print('hi')` 
However, when I try to group that class:

`group((MyTask.s() for i in range(10))()`

And I get error:

`Received unregistered task of type None`.

How can I fix this?